# iOS - NSNotificationCenter memory leak

Tags: iphone, ipad, memory-leaks, nsnotification

Instruments reports this a memory leak (98.6%, whatever that means):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kNotificationSomeNotification object:self];
```

"self" is a subclass of UIImageView. Is including "self" in the notification causing a memory leak? If so, how do you resolve it?

Comment: It's hard to tell with only a single line of code - can you add more?  I've been told that Apple has a reputation of having leaky code, so it could also be Apple's code and not yours.

Comment: @Gavin Miller can you quantify that? WebKit/`UIWebView` has definitely been leaky, but now is greatly improved in 4.1, but I can't think of another framework that would give Apple a "reputation" for "having leaky code"

Comment: @Shaggy Frog - I'm going based on what I've been told by other iOS developers. I also heard that back during 3.1 days; things could have changed since then, which would be awesome!

Answer (score 2):

Better check your notification observer. The cause of memory leak might be there.

Answer (score 1):

Memory leaks are almost always it is not safe. Check again are there leakage accurately!? You can do this by using deleaker.