# NSNotificationCenter memory leak

Tags: iphone, profiling, automatic-ref-counting, memory-leaks, nsnotificationcenter

I am profiling my app with Instruments and noticed that Leaks flags the code below as a memory leak:

```
- (void) onMessage:(DFTopicMessage *) message {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
     postNotificationName:@"serverMessage" 
     object:message];

}
```

More precisely, the line flagged as a leak is:

```
[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
```

I am using ARC in my project, so I wouldn't expect that. Would be very much interested in understanding what is wrong with this code and how to avoid the leak.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the process of debugging the same symptom.  It's been suggested in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002080/ios-nsnotificationcenter-memory-leak) that you check that the observer's selector doesn't over retain memory.  I would like to further elaborate by saying you can simply comment out all code in the selector and  verify this is where the leak occurs.  That being the case, I recommend you divide and conquer by un-commenting one line at a time to find the exact source of the issue.  Recursively apply this technique until the issue is staring you in the face.